# Animated Childrens Book App (iOS & Android)

Tags: android, ios, html, animation

I have a project where client wants to create children story book apps for both iOS & Android platform. They want something similar to these two apps:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/marie-de-paris/id586520420?ls=1&mt=8

https://itunes.apple.com/md/app/hello-i-am-charlie-from-london/id566826418?mt=8

There will be simple animation & sound effects in the app.

My question is what would be the best way to accomplish this? Are there any animation frameworks best suited for animated ebooks?

I'm familiar with native programming for both iOS & Android and I'm also open to Hybrid Development (HTML5).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If its simple animation you can use default or customized android animations. if the animations are complex, you may go ahead and use some opensource android framework engine like AND3D etc..